Google Sheets sum if
I have some problem with the code.. I'm stuck with summing 'COUNTA of PROBLEM INFO' by 'CODE'. I want to have for example: 0 --> (score) 11, 97 --> (score) 6.
SS
I tried to sum by xlookup or pivot tbl but it doesn't work exactly as planned? any ideas?


You may try this for 0 in Cell_B18 :
=sumif(A1:A13,A18,C1:C13)


You want to add value of all match. We can use filter and sum.
Filter value of desired cell:
=filter(range of values,range of match data=cell match,0 for exact match)

Simply put sum before it to get sum of all values:
=***sum(filter((range of values,range of match data=cell match,0 for exact match))***

In your sheet:
sum(filter(c2:c7,a2:a7=a18,0))

